# Creating a key/pair object using jQuery and some inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cart on my website and I need to let users easily change the quantity of items they have in their cart at a moment.

Here is the javascript code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var items = [];

        $(".item").each(function () {
            var productKey = $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val();
            var productQuantity = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();
            items.addKey(productKey, productQuantity); ?
        });

        // 1. Grab the values of each ammount input and it's productId.

        // 2. Send this dictionary of key pairs to a JSON action method.

        // 3. If results are OK, reload this page.
    });
</script>
```

The comments I wrote are just guidelines for me on how to proceed.

Is there a way to add a key/pair element to an array of sorts? I just need it to have a key and value. Nothing fancy.

I wrote in an `addKey()` method just for illustrative purposes to show what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
items[productKey] = productQuantity;
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, Arrays are Objects (`typeof(new Array)==='object'`), and Objects can have properties which can be get/set using dot- or bracket- syntax:

```javascript
var a = [1,2,3];
JSON.stringify(a); // => "[1,2,3]"
a.foo = 'Foo';
a.foo; // => 'Foo'
a['foo']; // => 'Foo'
JSON.stringify(a); // => "[1,2,3]"
```

So in your case, you can simply the productQuantity value to the productKey attribute of the `item` array as such:

```javascript
items[productKey] = productQuantity;
items[productKey]; // => productQuantity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add anonymous objects to the items array like:

```
items.push({
    key: productKey,
    quantity: productQuantity
});
```

Then access them later as `items[0].key` or `items[0].quantity`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use JQuery.data method and like that you can also get rid of those hidden.